# How to search for packages that are no longer available for installation?

Tags: debian, package-management

I can't re-install packages that fulfill at least one of the following criteria:

- Custom-made packages
- Packages created by **alien** package (e.g. `alien --install pkg.rpm`)
- Packages installed from some repository that is no longer available
- Packages installed from some repository, but is no longer available there
- Packages whose repositories have been removed from "**/etc/apt/sources.list**"

How do I list any of these packages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aptitude lists them under “Obsolete and Locally Created Packages”. The corresponding search pattern is `?obsolete` or `~o`.

```
aptitude search '?obsolete'
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to list packages installed via `alien` just by running `rpm -qa`.

For Debian packages, maybe some combination of `apt-cache policy` and `apt-get autoclean` can help?

> ```
>    autoclean
>        Like clean, autoclean clears out the local repository of retrieved
>        package files. The difference is that it only removes package files
>        that can no longer be downloaded, and are largely useless.
> ```

Comment: `autoclean` doesn't work as advertised; I guess I must file a bug

Comment: Does it work after doing `apt-get update`?

Comment: The command `rpm -qa` doesn't return anything, even though I have packages installed via alien; Has it worked for you before?

Comment: Yes, I did an update.

Comment: I'm not sure.  It would make sense if it worked, but I don't have any packages installed using alien that I can test with.

Comment: Sounds like I'm zero for two.  Sorry.

Comment: Actually, autoclean just removes packages from the cache. It doesn't uninstall them. Remember the cache is where packages are kept so they don't have to be re-fetched from a repo in case of a re-install.

Comment: I didn't say it uninstalled them.  The point is to see what it prints when you run it.  Perhaps even with `--dry-run` so you can do it multiple times without changing anything.